# DataStage Job "ABORTED" because of Deadlock issue

Tags: oracle, deadlock, etl, datastage

DataStage -- 8.1 
 Database -- Oracle 10g 
 OS -- Unix

I have a DataStage job (FCT) which is doing a lookup based on two keys columns to the DIM table. This job ABORTED with the following error message.

---

"main_program: (aptoci.C:483). Message: ORA-04020: deadlock detected while trying to lock object  DIM_TABLE_NAME  "

---

Partition type for lookup stage -- Auto 
 Config file Nodes -- 2

Note:- Most of the times this job runs without any issues but sometimes fail with the above error message.

Don't understand what can cause deadlock here and how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the deadlock trace file look like?  Is there invalid code in the schema?  Is the job doing DDL?  Is some other job doing DDL at the same time?

Comment: Thanks Justin for replying, for "deadlock trace file look like"--I need to request from DBA. The error related Stage is just reading from the oracle table. Its Oracle enterprise stage , Read Method -- Table, Auto Generated SQL option.